# How to display custom column names JTable and not from Database?

Tags: java, database, eclipse, windowbuilder

First I am using Eclipse, WindowBuilder and rs2xml.java, to work around with tables. 
My question is, is there a way to display, custom column names, eg. like in settings, and not from database ?

When i execute my code it set names from Database and not from settings and i don't want that ...

Show table:

```
public void MainTableShow() {

    try {

         String query="select Rb, Popisni_broj, Lokation, Kancelarija, Tip, Ispravnost from Main";

         PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement(query);
         ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
         tableMain.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));


         pst.close();
         rs.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```

and this is table settings done in WindowBuilder

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    tableMain = new JTable();
    tableMain.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
        new Object[][] {
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
        },
        new String[] {
            "Redni Broj", "Popisni Broj", "Lokacija", "Radno Mesto", "Tip opreme", "Ispravnost opreme"
        }
    ) {
        Class[] columnTypes = new Class[] {
            Integer.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, Boolean.class
        };
        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return columnTypes[columnIndex];
        }
        boolean[] columnEditables = new boolean[] {
            false, false, false, false, false, false
        };
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            return columnEditables[column];
        }
    });
    scrollPane.setViewportView(tableMain);
    textFieldSearch = new JTextField();
    textFieldSearch.setColumns(10);
```

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback ;-) ... and welcome to *upvote* levels ;-) x2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, your code basically says:

```
tableMain.setModel(...
```

twice. Most likely, the second call is the one that takes `DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)`). And that **second** model simply trumpets whatever you put there with your first call.

Thus the answer is: you can't use that utility call like that. I am *guessing* that the utility code in `DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel()` builds a model that solely uses values coming from the database.

If you want *adapt* that model, well, then you have to look into that utility method and *change* what it is doing. You could, for example have another utility method that also takes column names via code, and uses those instead of values coming from the DB.

But as you aren't disclosing that method with us, more specific advice isn't possible.